# session expire after exception caught in plsq sql oracle apex

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

we are doing custom authentication in oracle apex, 
if user enter charater (allow only number) INVALID_NUMBER exception appear in pl sql

message successfully appear by **apex_error.add_error**  but on next attempt we got message "Your session has expired", as i understand 
**apex_error.add_error** destroy session . My question is how to contain session alive after **apex_error.add_error**
or how to regenerate sesison after message

```
exception when INVALID_NUMBER then
  apex_error.add_error(
   p_message          => 'UserName Must be Number',
    p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can use `apex_util.set_custom_auth_status` for the notification.

```
apex_util.set_custom_auth_status (p_status => 'UserName Must be Number..!');
```